# Is it possible to databind a margin with an observable?

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I would like to databind a layout_marginBottom in my xml code. And link this bind into the code with an Observable variable.

I tried to put the databind in my view like this:

```
android:layout_marginBottom="@{viewModel.marginBottom}"
```

And then in my code have:

```
public final ObservableFloat marginBottom = new ObservableFloat(0);
```

But this won't compile, the error message is:

```
Error:(12, 36) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_marginBottom' with parameter type float on com.example.customView.
```

I tried with ObservableInt too but similar error message. Maybe I have to convert the int to a dp in some way? Is this possible? How do I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should not control your layout by data binding. But if you really want to do it, it should be perfectly fine to write a `@BindingAdapter` for the margins which modifies the `LayoutParams` of the `View`.

```
@BindingAdapter("layout_marginBottom")
public static void setMarginBottom(View view, int margin) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    if (params instanceof ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) params;
        margins.bottomMargin = margin;
        view.requestLayout();
    }
}
```